# Compile Error: User Type Not Defined - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am getting the error in the attached picture. This function worked perfectly until we were upgraded from MS Office 2007 to MS 2013 (although we didn't upgrade Access). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The `Public Function` line is the one causing the issue.

***Error Screenshot:***

[image]

Comment: The "Public Function" line is the one causing the issue.

Comment: I tested your procedure in Access 2010 and it works perfect. Maybe just type it all again. I have never used $ in variable names but did not cause an issue here. The ampersand (&) is usually preferred instead of + for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu *Tools, References* and remove the MISSING reference to the Excel 2007 library and replace it with a reference to the library of Excel 2013.